# "Segmentize" collection with lodash

Tags: javascript, collections, lodash

- I have a collection `col1`

  ```
  var col1 = [1, 8, 9, 10, 2, 54, 7];
  ```
- I have another collection `col2`

  ```
  var col2 = [1, 8, 23, 9, 46, 10, 2, 54, 78, 7]
  ```

  ...that I know it contains every element of `col1`, plus some other elements
- I want to obtain this :

  ```
  var col3 = [
     [1, 8],
     [9],
     [10, 2, 54],
     [7]
  ]
  ```

  `col1` "splitted", "segmentized" by `col2`

I'd like to use *lodash* functions for conciseness, but if someone brings an answer as vanilla JS, I'll accept the answer, and traduct it to *lodash* as an edit.

NB: I use ints for readability on SO, but my real collection contains objects.
NB2: each element is unique in both collections
NB3: elements that are common to both collections are in the same order

Comment: They're in the same order? Then this should be trivial.

Comment: Yes they are. Edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a plain Javascript algorithm will be shorter, faster, and easier to understand here:

```
var l = [],
    col3 = [l],
    i = 0;
for (var j=0; j<col2.length; j++)
    if (col1[i] == col2[j])
        l.push(col1[i++]);
    else
        col3.push(l = []);
```

Same thing, less concise, using a lodash loop:

```
var col1Pointer = 0;
var segment = [];
var col3 = [];
col3.push(segment);

_.foreach(col2, function(col2Item) {
  var col1Item = col1[col1Pointer];
  if (col1Item == col2Item) {
    col1Pointer++;
    segment.push(col1Item);
  } else {
    segment = [];
    col3.push(segment);
  }
});
```

I can't think of a proper pure lodash way - there just is no appropriate method. But we could write one ourselves:

```
_.mixin({
    splitOn: function(arr, callback, thisArg) {
        if (!arr.length) return [];
        callback = _.callback(callbac, thisArg);
        var seg = [],
            res = [seg];
        for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++)
            if (callback(arr[i], i, arr))
                res.push(seg = [])
            else
                seg.push(arr[i]);
        return res;
    }
});
```

and then use it like

```
var col3 = _.splitOn(col2, _.ary(_.partial(_.includes, col1), 1));
```

Comment: Clever, thanks. That works. I traducted it to lodash, kinda literally. Stil open to other clever strategies

Comment: ... however I basically disagree with "*easier to understand*" argument

Comment: @CyrilCHAPON: Too literally - you're just proving my point that lodash is harder to read here :-) Imo you shouldn't use `reduce` if you have to mutate free variables - that's what the accumulator is for.

Comment: "*Too literally*". Yep I know. Basically why I'm waiting for other approches more lodashy style. This is hardly traductible because it's vanilla oriented. I'm not looking for performance, as stated. Maybe something with _.difference any more loops on the arrays would be cleaner here.

Comment: I mean that if you traduct a `for` loop like this you should've just used `_.each`.

Comment: I don't see how "lodashy" style would help here. Yes, declarative functional programming would shine here, but because of pattern matching, tail recursion, and cons lists, not because of fancy helper functions.

Comment: Btw, this was not performance-oriented, but complexity-oriented. I didn't see any lodash solution with linear runtime.

Comment: I was thinking of a "find differences", "loop on col2 and break on differences" approach for example

Comment: About "`_.forEach`" and "`_.reduce`", isn't *reduce* a more semantic "declare a var, accumulate something in it through a `for`, and return var" ? [Docs](https://lodash.com/docs#reduce) says "*Reduces collection to a value which is the accumulated result of running each element in collection through iteratee*"

Comment: @CyrilCHAPON: Yes, it would be more semantic, if we'd care not to use any side effects. But we have those, and in fact `l` and `i` are results of the reduction just as well as `col3`. So if we can't (don't want to) write a pure function, we shouldn't try to make it look like one.

Comment: Ok got your point. Mean col3 isn't the only "output" of the pseudo-function. Editing to _.foreach

Comment: The mixin seems clever but I need time to analyse it. Will do. Thanks